# Define twig function for template include

Tags: function, templates, symfony, twig

I have a quick question:

I use for a project many different elements. They have to be editable so i group them and include them as a template like this:

```
{% include '::Fields/special.html.twig' with {'avg': 'avgvalue','class':'test','value':'myValue'} %}
```

Is there a possibillity to make a shortcut function for this, like:

```
{{ special(fieldvalues) }}
```

If so, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create twig `function` like:

```
<?php

// src\BW\MainBundle\Twig\BWExtension.php

namespace BW\MainBundle\Twig;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

class BWExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{    

    protected $container;

    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function getFunctions() {

        return array(
            new \Twig_SimpleFunction('special', array($this, 'specialFunction')),
        );
    }


    public function specialFunction($fieldvalues) {
        // handle of field values

        return $this->container->get('templating')->render('BWMainBundle:Main:test.html.twig'); // return string of rendered twig template
    }
}
```

And then define it as a service:

```
# src\BW\MainBundle\Resources\config\services.yml
services:
    bw_main.twig.bw_extension:
        class: BW\MainBundle\Twig\BWExtension
        arguments: ["@service_container"]
        tags:
            - { name: twig.extension }
```

Comment: You did what you wanted?

Comment: I will test it and respond in a short time - thank you in advance

Comment: So I did create this Twig Extension class, but how can I load a Template in the specialFunction() function?

Comment: Inject `@service_container` to this service and you can get access to `templating`. Check answer update